# How to convert a dataframe to a txt readable by Iramuteq and Alceste

Tags: r, text-mining, stringr

Iramuteq and Alceste are text mining programs (still very popular in France) which work on weirdly formatted txt files: each document in the corpus has to start with ****, then each corpus variable has to be encoded as *variablename_value (respecting some formatting rules) and the text to be analysed has to go on a new line. For example:

```
**** year_2021 country_france
Bonjour, je m appelle Dario
**** year_2021 country_germany
Guten Tag, ich heisse Dario
```

How can I convert a dataframe with texts and corpus variables as columns into this format?

Answer (score 0):

The following function can be used to convert any dataframe to such a txt file:

```
dataframe2iramuteq <- function(data, filename) {
  data %>% 
    rename_with(~str_replace_all(str_to_lower(.), "[\\W_]+", "")) %>% # clean column names
    drop_na() %>%
    mutate(across(1:ncol(.)-1, ~str_replace_all(., "[\\W_]+", "")), row = 1:n()) %>% # clean values
    gather(coln, value, -row) %>%
    group_by(row) %>%
    summarise(text = str_c("**** ", str_c("*", coln[-n()], "_", value[-n()], collapse = " "), "\n", last(value))) %>% 
    summarise(text = str_c(text, collapse = "\n")) %>% 
    pull(1) %>% 
    write_file(filename)
}
```

Note that the text to be analysed has to be in the last column of the dataframe, and the other columns are all considered as corpus variables.

For example, if I wanted to analyse the following dataframe:

```
starwars_names <- starwars %>% 
  select(2:11, 1)
```

I could use `dataframe2iramuteq(starwars_names, "my_file.txt")`